# React Native If the user is logged in, I don't want the app to go to the login page again when I come back between pages

Tags: javascript, react-native

login with token with submit

```
  const onSubmit = async (values: { username: string; password: string }) => {
    const credentials = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      login(values, {
        onSuccess: data => {
          resolve(undefined);
          dispatch(
            auth({
              user: true,
              token: data?.data,
            }),
          );
          if (!credentials) {
            Keychain.setGenericPassword(email, password);
          }
            props.navigation.navigate(SCREEN.tab);
        },
        onError: error => {
          reject;
        },
      });
    });
  };

  const isDisabled = () => {
    return email === '' || password === '';
  };
```

Login Page as seen above
When I come back from the main page, I do not want it to enter the login page, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are navigating to Screen.Tab, The new screen will be added in the stack above login page. So when you click back button you will be just redirected back to login.
Rather than doing navigation.navigate you should reset your navigation stack to Screen.Tab

Reference:-

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```